# Optimize prompt template for llama 2

Tags: chatbot, langchain, large-language-model, llama

I am working on a chatbot that retrieves information from documents. I use mainly the langchain framework and llama2 model.
I have created a prompt template following the community guidelines for this model. But I have noticed that most examples show a template in the following format:

> [INST]<<SYS>>\n
>
> system message
>
> \n<</SYS>>\n\n
>
> Context: {chat history (*optional*)}
>
> {context (*retrieved document chunks*)}
>
> User: {question} [/INST]

While this seems to work I have noticed in one [Huggingface article](https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2) that there is a slight difference:

> [INST] <<SYS>>
>
> {{ system_prompt }}
>
> <</SYS>>
>
> {{ user_msg_1 }} [/INST] {{ model_answer_1 }}
>
> [INST] {{ user_msg_2 }} [/INST]

So, you can see that the system message and the first user message are put within [INST] tags, and then each new user question is put into these tags too.
The way the prompt I have works is that each time I have this structure:

> [INST]<<SYS>>
>
> system message
>
> <</SYS>>
>
> Context: Human: msg1 \n AI answer1 \n Human: msg2 \n AI answer2 ...
>
> {context (the retrieved documents for the latest question}
>
> User: msg-n [/INST]

and not the [INST]usr msg[/INST] chain that seems to be shown in the huggingface template.

My question is, am I missing some logic here and should I make some modifications to the prompt that I currently use in order to improve the model's answer quality?

Below I provide also the code that I currently have written:

```
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.prompts import (
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    PromptTemplate
)

B_INST, E_INST = "[INST]", "[/INST]"
B_SYS, E_SYS = "<<SYS>>\n", "\n<</SYS>>\n\n"
INSTRUCTION_MESSAGE = """system message text"""


def build_instruction(history_flag):
    """
    Build an instruction for the chatbot based on the history flag.

    Parameters:
    - history_flag (bool): Flag indicating whether to include history in the instruction.

    Returns:
    - instruction (str): The generated instruction for the chatbot.
    """

    if history_flag:
        return """Context: {history}\n{context}\nUser: {question}"""
    else:
        return """Context: {context}\nUser: {question}"""


def build_qa_template_llama(system_message, history_flag):
    """
    Constructs template with system prompt and instruction based on history flag
    for llama2.

    Args:
        system_message (str): The system message to be included in the template.
        history_flag (bool): Flag indicating what template structure to adopt.

    Returns:
        str: The generated question and answer template.
    """

    system_prompt = B_SYS + system_message + E_SYS
    instruction = build_instruction(history_flag)

    return B_INST + system_prompt + instruction + E_INST

def get_prompt_template(model_type, history_flag, system_message=INSTRUCTION_MESSAGE):
    """
    Returns a prompt template and memory object for generating prompts in the chatbot.

    Args:
        system_message (str): Defaults to INSTRUCTION_MESSAGE.
        history_flag (bool): Flag indicating whether to include history variable. Defaults to False.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing the prompt template and memory object.
    """

    input_variables = ["context", "question"]
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(input_key="question", memory_key="history")
    if model_type == "llama":
        qa_template = build_qa_template_llama(system_message, history_flag)
    elif model_type == "mistral":
        qa_template = build_qa_template_mistral(history_flag)

    if history_flag:
        input_variables.append("history")

    prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=input_variables,
                            template=qa_template)

    return prompt, memory
```